# configuring ehCache : Cache is null

Tags: java, ehcache

I am new to using any caching tool, I tried using ehcache ... created my `ehcache.xml` in classpath which contains a `<cache name="xyz" .../>` entry.

But when I try to access my cache "xyz" from the init method of one my servlet, I am getting `null`:

```java
cacheManger.getCache("xyz") // <= is "null"
```

although

```java
cacheManager.getCacheNames()
```

is giving me `[xyz]`

I am using the following code:

```java
EhCacheManager.create();
ehcManager = EhCacheManager.getInstance();

System.out.println("getCacheNames::---" +  Arrays.toString(ehcManager.getCacheNames())); //here I get "xyz"

cache = ehcManager.getCache("xyz"); // here cache is null
cache.getCacheEventNotificationService().registerListener(new EhCacheFlushEventListener());
```

Any idea ... What am I missing?

Comment: which `EhCacheManager` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

EhCache has a [CacheManager](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/CacheManager.html) that you can use to get the cache:

```java
CacheManager manager = new CacheManager( "src/config/ehcache.xml" );
Cache cache = manager.getCache( "xyz" );
Element element = cache.get( "key1" );
```

Here are [more examples](http://ehcache.org/documentation/recipes) from ehcache.org

Comment: Yes..I tried that and its working...but I wonder why the singlton way didn't work...Whats the differance between CacheManager.getInstance().getCache("xyz") and new CacheManger().getCache("xyz")

Comment: no difference. If you look at the code, getInstance() calls create() that does: "singleton = new CacheManager();" for the first time. But according to your question, you are not using `CacheManager`, you are using a some kind of 3rd party implementation: `EhCacheManager`, and I believe that is the root cause. Using `net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager` solves the issue.

Comment: thats just a wrapper I created...EhCacheMananger extends CacheManager

Comment: it _does_ work by using ehcache APIs with no custom wrappers. Try to _not_ use your wrapper. Once it works without it ( and it _does_ ), you can focus on why your custom wrapper does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your ehcache.xml is on your classpath (root element, not in the subpackage)
if you using maven project structure, then place it in /src/main/resources dir.

That the code that works for me:

```
CacheManager cm = CacheManager.getInstance();
if (cm != null)
{
  Set<String> cacheNames = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(cm.getCacheNames()));
  LOG.debug("cacheNames: " + cacheNames);
  for(String cName: cacheNames)
  {
    LOG.debug("Cache: "+cm.getEhcache(cName));
  }
}
```

**NOTE: I'm using "getEhcache" method instead of "getCache"**

Also re-check your ehcache.xml config, perhaps you are missing defaultCache element, here an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache maxBytesLocalHeap="1024m">
 <sizeOfPolicy maxDepth="2000" />
 <defaultCache eternal="false" timeToLiveSeconds="600"/>
 <cache name="myCacheablePOJO" eternal="true" statistics="true">
  <searchable>
   <searchAttribute name="field1" />
   <searchAttribute name="field2" />
   <searchAttribute name="field3" />
  </searchable>
 </cache>
</ehcache>
```

Comment: It's indeed an important note:
using getEhCache() will return also decorated caches.